# Copy rows by rows to new sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have rows of data in Sheet1:

column A with Transaction Number
column B with Customer Name and
column C with Amount.

The rows can go up to a thousand in a month. I would like to copy and paste Row 1 to Row 10 to Range("D23:D32") and the following ten rows to Range("M23:M32"), and so on, to another new sheet.

How should I code in VBA?

Comment: If you have been trying for days, you should post your current code and explain why it doesn't meet your requirements.

Comment: Your question is not clear. If you copy rows then Cells in column A, B and C  will be overwritten in new sheet. Do you mean to say Range ("A2:C11") to go to Range ("D23:F32") and ("A12:C21") to go to ("M23:M32"). Secondly what about Header Row in the new sheet. If you upload sample images of your requirements to image hosting sites, some one may lead you in right direction.

Answer (score 2):

```
Sub Tester()
    Dim rngCopy As Range, rngPaste As Range
    Set rngCopy = Sheets("sheet1").Range("A1:C10")
    Set rngPaste = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("D23")
    Do While Application.CountA(rngCopy) > 0
        rngCopy.Copy Destination:=rngPaste
        Set rngCopy = rngCopy.Offset(10, 0)
        Set rngPaste = rngPaste.Offset(0, 9)
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: nice simple code. It transfers one block of data but the requirement specified is that it may extend to 1000 rows.

Comment: @skkakkar - why don't you try it out?